# How to split string with specific condition in Javascipt

Tags: javascript, string, split, string-concatenation, string-operations

I'm trying to split string with "&&" operator. but in my string there is some data with the same "&&" operator which I don't want to split. so is there any way or logic to ignore that operator for split data.

**string -**

> let str = "countryid == 45 &&
> (payerid==82||payerid==84||payerid==79) && (fobid!=1&&fobid!=2)"

**Code -**

> let breakCond = str.split('&&');

**Result -**

```
0: "countryid == 45 "
1: " (payerid==82||payerid==84||payerid==79) "
2: " (fobid!=1"
3: "fobid!=2) "
```

**Expected Result -**

```
0: "countryid == 45 "
1: " (payerid==82||payerid==84||payerid==79) "
2: " (fobid!=1&&fobid!=2) "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you could simply include the white spaces.

```
let breakCond = str.split(' && ');
```

If that doesn't do it than you would have to create your own version of split with its own logic.

Comment: Yes @NewRhino , it is working by including white spaces. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if there are always no spaces in the ones you want to keep. you can just use:

```
str.split(' && ')
```

Comment: it'll work with the provided string.

Comment: Yes @Aizaz it is working by by including white spaces. Thank you.